# Oracle SQL Table says Missing Right Parenthesis on Create Statement Why?

Tags: oracle, ddl, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE Edit 
(
    editID numeric(5) PRIMARY KEY , 
    CONSTRAINT edit_fk FOREIGN KEY (adminID)
         REFERENCES Admin (adminID)
              ON DELETE CASCADE
              ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT edit_fk FOREIGN KEY (flgihtID)
         REFERENCES Flight (flightID)
              ON DELETE CASCADE
              ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Reservation 
(
    reservationID numeric(5) PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT reservation_fk FOREIGN KEY (flightID)
         REFERENCES Flight (flightID)
              ON DELETE CASCADE
              ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as `ON UPDATE CASCADE` in Oracle. There might be in other RDMBSs, but not Oracle. Take that clause out.